# Error: variable names are limited to 10000 bytes

Tags: r

I'm getting this error in my r instance

```
Error: variable names are limited to 10000 bytes
```

I imported only a single CSV and it was working earlier.

I'm doing some modeling, so I'm wondering if that what might be causing it.

I'll update the output from ls()

```
> ls()
 [1] "analysisOfVarianceDiagnosticPlotsText" "analysisOfVarianceSummaryText"         "bivariate"                            
 [4] "columns2newname"                       "convert.to.factors"                    "convert.to.numerics"                  
 [7] "convert.to.ordinals"                   "convert2character"                     "convert2factor"                       
[10] "convert2numeric"                       "convert2ordinal"                       "cycleThruCounts"                      
[13] "dataset"                               "definitions"                           "formula"                              
[16] "fTestText"                             "GCtorture"                             "importPackages"                       
[19] "input_names"                           "list.of.names"                         "model"                                
[22] "print.selfcat"                         "regressionModel"                       "response_name"                        
[25] "selectRegressionModelCoefficients"     "split_sets"                            "student_performance"                  
[28] "student_performance_md"                "student_performance_old"               "student_performance_v1"               
[31] "subset_filter"                         "subsetSelection"                       "subsetSelectionText"                  
[34] "summPairwiseAnalysisofVarianceText"    "test_dataset"                          "test_set"                             
[37] "train_dataset"                         "train_set"                             "univariate"                           
[40] "unpairedTwoSampleTTestText"            "x"                                     "y"
```

I'm on the latest version of R on the latest Catalina on a Macbook pro

I just ran this command on a dataset with 400 rows

```
student_performance <-
  read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UBC-MDS/ellognea-smwatts-student-performance/master/data/student-math-perf.csv") %>% 
  as_tibble()

formula <- c("G3 ~ .")

     subsetSelection <-
          summary(regsubsets(as.formula(formula),
                          method = "exhaustive",
                          really.big = T,
                          data = dataset))
```

I think it has to do with my import function

```
importPackages <- function(){
  
  list.of.packages <-     
    c("conflicted",
      "RSQLite", 
      "lubridate",
      "ggfortify",
      "tidycomm",
      "ggrepel",
      "DALEX",
      "mlbench",
      "mgcv",
      "olsrr",
      "pec",
      "reactable",
      "textclean",
      "leaps",
      "faraway",
      "tidyverse", 
      "caret",
      "party",
      "stringr",
      "fpp",
      "plotly",
      "gsl",
      "randomForest",
      "PerformanceAnalytics",
      "rpart",
      "metafolio",
      "splines",
      "summarytools",
      "car",
      "ggraph",
      "igraph",
      "stringr",
      "hrbrthemes", 
      "TTR",
      "knitr",
      "ggridges",
      "MASS",
      "outliers",
      "kableExtra",
      "Hmisc",
      "xts",
      "TSstudio",
      "tseries",
      "MLmetrics",
      "scales",
      "survival",
      "survminer",
      "BTYD",
      "sqldf", 
      "RColorBrewer",
      "DT")

  new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
  if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
    
  for (i in seq_along(list.of.packages)){ library(list.of.packages[i], character.only = T)}
  
    theme_set(theme_bw())
    conflict_prefer("filter", "dplyr", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("summarize", "dplyr", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("lag", "dplyr", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("quarter", "lubridate", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("vif", "faraway", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("R2", "caret", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("RMSE", "caret", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("explain", "DALEX", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("select", "dplyr", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("days", "lubridate", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("week", "lubridate", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("%--%", "lubridate", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("between", "dplyr", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("month", "lubridate", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("decompose", "stats", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("year", "lubridate", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("list", "base", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("weeks", "lubridate", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("quarters", "lubridate", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("as_data_frame", "tibble", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("boundary", "stringr", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("cluster", "caret", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("clusters", "modeltools", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("col_factor", "readr", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("collapse", "dplyr", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("combine", "dplyr", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("simplify", "purrr", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("compose", "purrr", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("crossing", "tidyr", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("discard", "scales", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("first", "dplyr", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("getResponse", "forecast", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("gghistogram", "forecast", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("group_rows", "kableExtra", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("groups", "dplyr", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("label", "summarytools", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("label<-", "summarytools", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("last", "dplyr", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("layout", "plotly", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("legend", "graphics", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("lift", "caret", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("MAE", "caret", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("margin", "randomForest", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("neighborhood", "igraph", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("Position", "ggplot2", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("Recall", "MLmetrics", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("outlier", "outliers", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("spectrum", "stats", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("src", "dplyr", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("subplot", "plotly", quiet = T)
    conflict_prefer("view", "tibble", quiet = T)

    
}

importPackages()
```

It gave me this error

```
 Error in data.frame(values = unlist(unname(x)), ind, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  variable names are limited to 10000 bytes 
8.
data.frame(values = unlist(unname(x)), ind, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
7.
stack.default(x) 
6.
utils::stack(x) 
5.
invert(objs) 
4.
conflict_scout(pkgs) 
3.
conflicts_register() 
2.
library(list.of.packages[i], character.only = T) 
1.
importPackages()
```

Comment: I included dots in some of my variable names. Could that be the cause?

Comment: I restarted R and it fired before I even started the modeling, so that's not the cause